# HTACCESS Redirect if title empty

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have url like this: http://mydomain.tld/product/dynamic-title.html

the problem is when i try access with no title like this:
http://mydomain.tld/product/.html

it still shown page, i want to redirect to homepage or 404.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/*product\/\.html$ . [L]
```

the regex above not working..

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have this rule for that condition:

```
RewriteRule ^product/\.html$ / [L,R,NC]
```

OR a more generic rule to catch all `/.html` URIs:

```
RewriteRule /\.html$ / [L,R,NC]
```

Comment: i just try it's not redirected. seems caused rule after your code.
is it possible to make any line after your code not executed? 
thank you

Comment: I didn't understand your comment. Are you saying rule didn't work? If yes then tell me which URL you tried and didn't work? Yes it's possible to prevent further rules after this rule but I just don't have all the details of your requirement.

Comment: @Downvoter: May I know the reason of down vote for my education.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `/*` from your code, do not escape slash character `/` and redirect such request to root `/`

```
RewriteRule ^product/\.html$ / [L]
```

Left side of `RewriteRule` contains relative path after **host/**, so for http://mydomain.tld/product/.html it is just **product/.html**, nothing before word **product**.